# Convert Gimp "Color Enhance" algorithm to python

Tags: opencv, colors, gimp, hsv

I am trying to code the same effect as "Color Enhance" in Gimp. Here is the doc: https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/plug-in-color-enhance.html

Basically it says : *It does this by converting the colors to HSV space, measuring the range of saturation values across the image, then stretching this range to be as large as possible, and finally converting the colors back to RGB. It is similar to Stretch Contrast, except that it works in the HSV color space, so it preserves the hue.*

I tried to implement the algorithm that way:

```
def enhanced(hsv):
    h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
    s_equ = cv2.equalizeHist(s)

    hsv_image = cv2.merge([h, s_equ, v])
    out = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_image, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite("out.jpg", out)


img2 = cv2.imread("IMG_0233.jpg")

hsv2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

enhanced(hsv2)
```

But I do not have the same result as Gimp:

Input image:

[image]

Result of Gimp color Enhance:

[image]

Result with my script:

[image]

Is there anything that I am missing? Many thanks.

Comment: Try normalising rather than equalising.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I tried to normalize only the saturation channel like this : sat_mod = cv2.normalize(s, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) and then merge this channel with Hue and Val. But when I compare the original saturation channel and sat_mod, values are the same! So no effect on my new image.

Comment: Indeed min and max value in saturation channel are already 0 and 255, so no effect on my new image. So Gimp is no doing this as there is a clear change in the image.

Comment: Try plotting the saturation histogram of your input image, your output image and GIMP's output image beside each other on the same scale.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly one (likely Gimp) is working on "linear light" (likely if you are using the GEGL, non-legacy version of "Color enhance") while the other is using gamma-compressed values. In Gimp you can use the Pointer dialog to have the HSV value of pixels, and compare to what CV produces.

The source of the Gimp 2.10 color-enhance is here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/-/blob/master/operations/common/color-enhance.c

The comments state:

```
 * This operation is inspired from the color enhance gimp plugin.
 * It alters the chroma component to cover maximum possible range,
 * keeping hue and lightness untouched.
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, Opérations are done in CIELAB. Just tried this: lab_picture = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB) then after splitting in the 3 [lab] channels: a_norm = cv2.normalize(a, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX), and then out = cv2.merge((l, a_norm, b). Finally convert back to BGR img_out = cv2.cvtColor(out, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR) and use imwrite. I obtained the original image but with a lot of green. So there is still something that I am missing.